# Displaying Annotation text at the top of the graph in Google Charts

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, react-google-charts

I currently have a line chart that I've created in Google charts and have a question that I can't seem to find in the docs. Attached is a picture of what I need, but in text:

I need to be able to annotate specific values along the x-axis with a vertical line, but instead of having the text labels rotated to be perpendicular to the x-axis (see: [How can I add a vertical line on the X axis in a Google Chart' chart (Line type)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52891016/how-can-i-add-a-vertical-line-on-the-x-axis-in-a-google-chart-chart-line-type)), I need the text to be above the vertical line at the top of the graph, parallel to the x-axis.

Here is a drawn image of what I'm looking for:

[image: Graph that I need]

I was thinking maybe doing this with annotations, but open to any ideas.

Comment: `I currently have a line chart that I've created in Google charts` - add in your question the chart you created.

Comment: you can use a line series to draw the lines, then add an annotation to the last line value of each series.

Comment: @WhiteHat What exactly do you mean by a line series? I can't think of a good way to make a straight vertical line with data.

Comment: @trevocrupi check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59688436/5090771), to get a vertical line, add two rows with the same x axis value, with values for the min and max y axis values.